# How do I display table with header once, followed by multiple database field contents, if fields are not empty?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to get:

**Quotes:**
Quote 1
Quote Source 1

Quote 2
Quote Source 2

I currently get:

**Quotes:**
Quote 1
Quote Source 1

**Quotes:**
Quote 2
Quote Source 2

Final Code that works for me:

```
  echo ("<table border='1'>");

$header_printed = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
if ($row['quote']) {
    if ($header_printed === false) {
        echo "   

            <tr>
                <th>Quotes:</th>
            </tr>";
        $header_printed = true;
    }

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".$row['quote']."</td>
            <td>".$row['quote_source']."</td>
        </tr>";
}

}

echo ("</table>");
```

Comment: By not opening a new table for every quote, but doing that once before the loop, and writing only a new TR element in each loop step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the header out of the loop:

```
$header_printed = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    if ($row['quote']) {
        if ($header_printed === false) {
            echo "   
                <table border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quotes:</th>
                </tr>";
            $header_printed = true;
        }

        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>".$row['quote']."</td>
                <td>".$row['quote_source']."</td>
            </tr>";
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to make the header appear once only if there is data in ($row['quote'])  So no data, no header.  But if there is data, header appears once.

Comment: Edited the answer so the script would print the header only if there is data to display.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Quotes:</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    if ($row['quote']) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['quote']."</td><td>".$row['quote_source']."</td></tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  The only remaining issue is it still echos <th>Quotes</th> even if there is no data in the $row['quote'] fields.  Sorry, I know my question was not clear.